# How to upload multiple files on AWS S3 and storing the url to Firebase using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, firebase

I am using AWS S3 as hosting (files) and firebase as database and its working fine for single file upload?
Is there any way to upload multiple images on S3 by Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by AWS S3 Cognito try this link here :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Amazon_S3

**Also try this code**

Just change Region, IdentityPoolId and Your bucket name

[github Link](https://github.com/rishiv3/s3-multiple-file-upload-angularJS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>AWS S3 File Upload</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.12.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-chooser" />
    <button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.region = 'your-region'; // 1. Enter your region
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'your-IdentityPoolId' // 2. Enter your identity pool
    });
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
        if (err) alert(err);
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
    });
    var bucketName = 'your-bucket'; // Enter your bucket name
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: bucketName
        }
    });
    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
    var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var file = fileChooser.files[0];
        if (file) {
            results.innerHTML = '';
            var objKey = 'testing/' + file.name;
            var params = {
                Key: objKey,
                ContentType: file.type,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };
            bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
                } else {
                    listObjs(); // this function will list all the files which has been uploaded
                    //here you can also add your code to update your database(MySQL, firebase whatever you are using)
                }
            });
        } else {
            results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
        }
    }, false);
    function listObjs() {
        var prefix = 'testing';
        bucket.listObjects({
            Prefix: prefix
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
            } else {
                var objKeys = "";
                data.Contents.forEach(function(obj) {
                    objKeys += obj.Key + "<br>";
                });
                results.innerHTML = objKeys;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase engineer:

I'd recommend using our newest product, [Firebase Storage](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start), which is a Firebase wrapper around [Google Cloud Storage](http://cloud.google.com/storage) to provide secure, resumable uploads and downloads, directly from mobile clients--it basically replaces this with a Firebase Database integrated solution! We've also got a generous free tier and competitive pricing after that, and an API that is also directly compatible with S3 (through Google Cloud Storage).